# Looping through longitude list and latitude list to compute their distances and store the value in a matrix. TSP

Tags: python, dataframe, geocoding

I have a dataframe of establishments with their respective addresses & geocoded lat/long coordinates. I want to run a TSP algorithm to determine the optimal tour and distance for the route. To do this I need to create a distance matrix.

To calculate the distances I am using this formula: `69*sqrt((lat1-lat2)^2+(long1-long2)^2`
I went ahead and created the matrix in excel for reference. My code does work, however it does not return the correct distances. I am a python beginner and could use all the help, thank you in advanced.

I tried to get the df columns and converted them into lists. I then added the start/end lat/long coordinates to the beginning of each list.

I iterated through every value of the list and plugged it into the formula. **this is the part where I am unsure where the error is* because it does output a distance matrix, however it not the correct one.

Does anyone have any suggestions or alternative methods to obtain the following matrix?
[Distance Matrix calculated in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyGaf.png) (the empty values mirror those over the diagonal and my desired python output should be the complete table)

[Getting Distance Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKoEV.png)

Once I get this piece I can plug it into this line of code which does run but the value outputted is incorrect because the distance matrix is incorrect:

```py
permutation, distance_distf = solve_tsp_dynamic_programming(distf_matrix_01)
```

Comment: You can't compute distances accurately between points specified via their longitude and latitude using the Euclidean distance formula. To calculate distances between points on a sphere you need to use the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). Here's a link to a popular [Python implementation](https://gist.github.com/rochacbruno/2883505) by Wayne Dyck, and here's another [Distance on a sphere: The Haversine Formula](https://community.esri.com/t5/coordinate-reference-systems-blog/distance-on-a-sphere-the-haversine-formula/ba-p/902128). Your mileage may vary.  ;¬)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with **list comprehension**:

```
matrix = [[distance(point0, point1) for point1 in point_list] for point0 in point_list]
```